# Mule esb file compression/encode and de-compress/decode

Tags: decode, mule, encode, compression

I want to use Mule esb to transfer files between Magento and OFbiz. I know hot to use mule to transfer flat files between systems, but could not find helpful tutorial or info on how to use Mule to compress and encode files to be transferred, and also to decompress and decode received (compressed/encoded) files on the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mule's gzip-compress-transformer for compression and gzip-uncompress-transformer
to decompress. What encoding and decoding mechanims you are refering to ?

Comment: Yep, the gzip-compress-transformer/gzip-uncompress-transformer works. Thanks hi10